# Extract HTML link from inside DOM header resource (without ID or class)

Tags: javascript, dom, selectors-api

I have the following code structure on a site:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="http://example.com/?amp"></head>
```

I am looking to extract the html link only on pages where the "amphtml" rel value appear. I tried the following code but it breaks the application on urls where that tag does not appear.

```
var ampLink_txt = document.querySelector("link[rel=amphtml]").getAttribute("href");
```

I don't have access to change the HTML document, do I can't add any ID's or classes. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check if it's null first?

Answer (score 0):

`.querySelector` may return `null` if nothing is found. You should check first if it's null:

```
const ampLink = document.querySelector("link[rel=amphtml]")

if (ampLink) {
   const ampLink_txt = ampLink.getAttribute("href")
   // ...
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfect! Really really appreciate it